# Yahoo finance comet technique

Tags: jquery, yahoo-finance, comet

There is a comet-based stock quotes fetching technique that Yahoo Finance uses

The commet url:
http://streamerapi.finance.yahoo.com/streamer/1.0?s=AAPL&k=l10,a00,b00&callback=parent.yfs_u1f&mktmcb=parent.yfs_mktmcb&gencallback=parent.yfs_gencb

The endless response:

```
<html><head><script type='text/javascript'> document.domain='finance.yahoo.com'; </script> </head><body></body><script>try{parent.yfs_u1f({"AAPL":{l10:"604.00",a00:"603.70",b00:"603.36"}});}catch(e){}</script>
```

And once the stock quote changes in realtime the response grows, appending this:

```
<script>try{parent.yfs_u1f({"AAPL":{l10:"604.10",a00:"603.70",b00:"603.36"}});}catch(e){}</script>
```

So I'm trying to catch this data by creating iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://streamerapi.finance.yahoo.com/streamer/1.0?s=AAPL&k=l10,a00,b00&callback=parent.yfs_u1f&mktmcb=parent.yfs_mktmcb&gencallback=parent.yfs_gencb" />
```

And a script to process the function:

```
<script>function yfs_u1f(data){alert(data);}</script>
```

but the script is not executed, i guess because of same origin policy.

How can I get around of this issue?

Comment: Do you see an error in the console? If not, try not to catch exceptions in your script, so you can know exactly why it doesn't work.

If the problem is indeed that the yahoo stream does not declare Access-Control-Allow-Origin, best solution I can think of is to set up your own server relaying the data :(